# Waypoint specific yaw_goal_tolerance for move base

Tags: navigation, move-base, rosparam, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to specify a yaw_goal_tolerance for each waypoint you send to move_base? Sometimes I care which direction it ends up in and other times I don't care. And using dynamic reconfigure sounds overly complicated and would result in much less readable code and would be harder to debug.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268518/waypoint-specific-yaw_goal_tolerance-for-move-base/) by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 545 on 2017-08-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-10**:
Are asking about setting the `yaw_goal_tolerance` parameter for the `base_local_planner` dynamically?

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2017-08-11**:
Yes, that is correct. Id also like to note that I've noticed that when using dynamic reconfigure, if you mess something up it fails silently. Which is terrible for debug. It would also make code less readable so before going through all the work to set that up I'm wondering if there is an easier way

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-09-07**:
I currently monitor the distance and angle in a separate node and cancel the goal if I'm close enough.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-09-07**:
Also other planners like teb_local_planner might give you the option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK there is no such option, unfortunately.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0